# Регулярное выражение для поиска строк, заключенных в кавычки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно для подсветки кода

Пробовал подобное:

```
/('[^']*')|("[^"]*")/g
```

Но нужно чтобы находило строки в кавычках, но не искало при этом строки в тегах.

```
<span class="keyword">"while"</span>
```

В данном примере выделена должна быть только while.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @gx206 Вы бы привели кусок текста в котором присутствует что должно находиться и что не должно. И написали что именно должно быть найдено. Тогда может и можно регулярку будет сделать. Но вообще раз у вас вопросы по подсветке и вы это делаете регулярками то готовтесь писать сотню регулярок на разные случаи

Comment: Mike. Ищу в коде javascript, php (подсветку снипетов для себя делаю). После обвертки операторов и ключевых слов появляются теги с атрибутами вот в них и не надо чтоб искало. Пока решил как ты сказал перенес оператор class в отдельную регулярку.

Comment: чтобы не попадать в такую ситуацию, делайте замену в один проход

Comment: @gx206 Кажется понял, надо выбирать значения в кавычках, но при этом не атрибуты тегов. Т.е. `<A href="xxx">"aaa"</A>` должно вернуть aaa, но не должно вернуть xxx, так ? И регулярка кстати на чем разбирается, на JS или чем то другом ? просто у JS регулярки сильно покоцанные, многого нельзя делать. И что кстати с обратными косыми, выделение не ломают ?

Comment: @gx206 И она должна вернуть найденное именно в первой подмаске, если будут вторая и т.п. подмаски в выражении, не имеющие отношения к делу, это не страшно ?

Comment: @Mike Да правильно. Разбираю JS (первое совпадение обворачиваю span с соответствующим классом). Просто с регулярками не особо имел дело. Ковычки ищу только одинарные и двойные косых там нет.

Comment: @Mike "[^"]*"[^>] - что то вроде этого в онлайн тестере срабатывает а так нет

Comment: @gx206 Ну такие простые вещи то везде должны быть рабочими, только ведь необязательно, что `>` обязательно после кавычек стоит. тег то и сложнее может быть `<A href="xxx" style="xxx" class="yyy">` в общем в голову пока не приходит как такое вообще сделать.

Comment: @gx206 Вот такая `(?><.+?>)*((["']).*?\2)?` регулярка отлично выделяет в строке только значения в любых кавычках вне тегов. Она работает для PCRE, т.е. в php работать должна. Движок JS ее не поймет

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что для таких задач регулярные выражения плохо подходят, лучше использовать какие-нибудь парсеры, которые разбивают текст на токены, и потом уже можно првоерять парность кавычек, их тип (одинарные / двойные) и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Искомое регулярное выражение [выглядит так](https://regex101.com/r/fD3zY2/1):

```
/(?><.+?>)*((["']).*?\2)?/g
```

Вы к сожалению не указали какой язык будет работать с данным выражением. Оно использует возможности PCRE, т.е. оно будет работать в perl и php, но JS, к сожалению, такого не понимает.

В данном выражении:

1. `(?>)` Проверка подстроки без захвата и с запретом возврата назад по строке. Вот как раз она проходит теги, не позволяя остальной части выражения захватить в нем кавычки.
2. `(["'])` Захватывает двойную или одинарную кавычку, при этом это - подвыражение No 2 в нашей регулярке, поэтому чуть позже по тексту `\2` заставляет искать в строке точно такую же кавычку, т.е. двойную для двойной открывающей.

Так как вы в комментариях говорили, что регулярка для работы с кодом php/js то совсем правильно она должна [выглядеть так](https://regex101.com/r/cW6aY9/1):

```
/(?><.+?>)*((["'])(?:|(?:.*?)(?:[^\\]|[^\\]?(?:\\{2})+))\2)?/g
```

Этот вариант нормально работает с экранированными кавычками внутри строк, c учетом возможности экранирования самого символа экранирования.